# How to read serial port communication into buffer and parse out complete messages

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am using the following code to read values from a com port:

```
Private port As New SerialPort("COM13", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)

Private Sub port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Debug.Print(port.ReadExisting())
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler port.DataReceived, New SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(AddressOf port_DataReceived)
    port.Open()
End Sub
```

This works just fine, but every now and then it doesnt get all the data and in return results in two strings instead of just one.

An example would be if the com port was sending over the word "HELLO2YOU" it was look like:

```
HEL
LO2YOU
```

or

```
HELLO2
YOU
```

How can i place a buffer in there so that it makes sure it has all the data read before displaying it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to think of Serial Port communications as streaming data.  Any time you receive data, you have to expect that it may be a complete message, only a partial message, or multiple messages.  It all depends how fast the data is coming in and how fast you application is able to read from the queue.  Therefore, you are right in thinking you need a buffer.  However, what you may not be realizing yet, is that there is no way to know, strictly via, the Serial Port, where each message begins and ends.  That has to be handled via some agreed upon protocol between the sender and the receiver.  For instance, many people use the standard start-of-text (STX) and end-of-text (ETX) characters to indicate the beginning and ending of each message send.  That way, when you receive the data, you can tell when you have received a complete message.

For instance, if you used STX and ETX characters, you could make a class like this:

```
Public Class DataBuffer
    Private ReadOnly _startOfText As String = ASCII.GetChars(New Byte() {2})
    Private ReadOnly _endOfText As String = ASCII.GetChars(New Byte() {4})

    Public Event MessageReceived(ByVal message As String)
    Public Event DataIgnored(ByVal text As String)

    Private _buffer As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder

    Public Sub AppendText(ByVal text As String)
        _buffer.Append(text)
        While processBuffer(_buffer)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Function processBuffer(ByVal buffer As StringBuilder) As Boolean
        Dim foundSomethingToProcess As Boolean = False
        Dim current As String = buffer.ToString()
        Dim stxPosition As Integer = current.IndexOf(_startOfText)
        Dim etxPosition As Integer = current.IndexOf(_endOfText)
        If (stxPosition >= 0) And (etxPosition >= 0) And (etxPosition > stxPosition) Then
            Dim messageText As String = current.Substring(0, etxPosition + 1)
            buffer.Remove(0, messageText.Length)
            If stxPosition > 0 Then
                RaiseEvent DataIgnored(messageText.Substring(0, stxPosition))
                messageText = messageText.Substring(stxPosition)
            End If
            RaiseEvent MessageReceived(messageText)
            foundSomethingToProcess = True
        ElseIf (stxPosition = -1) And (current.Length <> 0) Then
            buffer.Remove(0, current.Length)
            RaiseEvent DataIgnored(current)
            foundSomethingToProcess = True
        End If
        Return foundSomethingToProcess
    End Function


    Public Sub Flush()
        If _buffer.Length <> 0 Then
            RaiseEvent DataIgnored(_buffer.ToString())
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I should also mention that, in communication protocols, it is typical to have a checksum byte by which you can determine if the message got corrupted during its transmission between the sender and the receiver.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite normal, serial ports are very slow devices.  With baudrates like 9600 and the machine not bogged down too much, you'll get only one or two bytes from the port when you use ReadExisting().  Debug.Print() outputs a line terminator so you'll see whatever is received broken up in pieces.

The easiest way to fix it is by using ReadLine() instead.   That requires that the devices sends a special character at the end of the line, one that matches the SerialPort.NewLine property value.  Which is quite common, a line feed is boilerplate.

If not then you'll need some other kind of buffering scheme.

Comment: Hans is correct that ReadLine() is an easy way to get complete messages terminated by a "newline" value. However, I would avoid using ReadLine since it is normally implemented as a blocking function and will degrade the performance of your GUI and other tasks. Normally I would buffer the characters into an array until I received the terminating character, then call the command parser.

Comment: No, not when you call it in the DataReceived event handler, it runs on a threadpool thread.